# When click on modal button code executed many times ( JQuery - JavaScript )

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

please i have a problem

when i click on a modal button the code inside it executed many time, for example if i click on modal button one time the code executed one time if i click on modal button two time the code executed two times and ect...

I work with JQuery

Modal HTML

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="CONFIRM_mdModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="defaultModalLabel">Confirm</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="CONFIRM_MODAL_MESSAGE">

                Confirm Message

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link waves-effect" id="Confirm_btn_YES">Yes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Java Script code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ADD_BTN").click(function() {
    if ($("#CODE").val() != '' && $("#INTTL").val() != '') {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Admin/IsFlExist',
        datatype: JSON,
        data: {
          'CODE': $("#CODE").val(),
          'INTTL': $("#INTTL").val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
          if (data.IsExist == "true") {
            showNotification("bg-orange", "xxxxx", "top", "right", "animated bounceInRight", "animated bounceOutRight");
          } else {
            Show_Confirm_Modal("Confirm", "xxxxx");
            $("#Confirm_btn_YES").one('click', function() {
              $("#form_validation").submit();
              $('#CONFIRM_mdModal').modal('hide');
            });
          }
        },
        error: function() {
          alert("Error");
        }
      });
    } else {
    }
  });
});
```

Function I use to show modal

```js
    function Show_Confirm_Modal(TITLE, MESSAGE)
    {

        var color = "teal";
        $('#CONFIRM_mdModal .modal-content').removeAttr('class').addClass('modal-content modal-col-' + color);
        $("#defaultModalLabel").empty().append(TITLE);
        $("#CONFIRM_MODAL_MESSAGE").empty().append(MESSAGE);
        $('#CONFIRM_mdModal').modal('show');

    }
```

Please i want to execute the FORM.Submit just one time, and massive thanks in advance.

Note : i see all the questions here about this problem but no one help me.

Comment: A common cause of this is adding an event handler inside another event handler. But I don't see that in your code. Is there more code you aren't showing?

Comment: `datatype: JSON,` should be `datatype: 'JSON',`

Comment: `.empty().append(TITLE)` can be written more simply as `.html(TITLE)`

Comment: a lot of thanks bro the problem maybe in JSON SHOULD BE 'JSON'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my situation is `JSON` should be `'JSON'`, that's help me

thank you all

Comment: I don't see how this could cause double execution. It should just cause errors.